# Ordering multiple entry points in Webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I have multiple entries in my Webpack config:

```
entry: {
'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
'app': './src/main.ts'
},
```

When I run `npm start` (`webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080 --bail`) the `\<my-app>Loading...</my-app>` in my index.html turns into scripts in this order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/common.js"> <!--I also have CommonsChunkPlugin-->
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/app.js"></script>
```

But when I run `webpack -p --progress --profile --bail` it's in this order:

> *common, app, polyfil, then vendor*

Order is important. My app.js code won't work if run before polyfil.js or vendor.js. **How do I control the order?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the 'manual' option these days :

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    chunks: ['polyfill', 'vendor', 'bundle'],
    chunksSortMode: 'manual',
}),
```

Comment: simply putting the entries in order in webpack, works fine for me. `entry: {
        // order matters
        polyfills: './src/polyfills.ts',
        vendor: './src/vendor.ts',
        main: './src/main.ts',
    }`

Comment: I think if the "polyfill" entry point has a dependency that lives in the vendor bundle, webpack will print the script tag for the vendor bundle out first regardless of the `chunks` config.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a helper in order to accomplish it:

```
function packageSort(packages) {
    // packages = ['polyfills', 'vendor', 'app']
    var len = packages.length - 1;
    var first = packages[0];
    var last = packages[len];
    return function sort(a, b) {
      // polyfills always first
      if (a.names[0] === first) {
        return -1;
      }
      // app always last
      if (a.names[0] === last) {
        return 1;
      }
      // vendor before app
      if (a.names[0] !== first && b.names[0] === last) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    }
  }
```

And in your webpack config file:

```
plugins.index = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template:       'src/index.html',
  filename:       'index.html',
  chunksSortMode: packageSort(['polyfills', 'vendor', 'app'])
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @EdmarMiyake for pointing me in the direction of chunksSortMode. I tried setting it to 'dependency' first, but that didn't seem to work. In the end I resorted to this:

```
function packageSort(packages) {
    return function sort(left, right) {
        var leftIndex = packages.indexOf(left.names[0]);
        var rightindex = packages.indexOf(right.names[0]);

        if ( leftIndex < 0 || rightindex < 0) {
            throw "unknown package";
        }

        if (leftIndex > rightindex){
            return 1;
        }

        return -1;
    }
};
```

and

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'src/index.html',
  chunksSortMode: packageSort(['common', 'polyfills', 'vendor', 'app'])
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

This function could be even better: you give the list of the element you want to place at first in your html file

```
function packageSort(packages) {
    return function sort(left, right) {
        var leftIndex = packages.indexOf(left.names[0]);
        var rightindex = packages.indexOf(right.names[0]);
        if (rightindex < 0) {
            return -1;
        }

         if ( leftIndex < 0) {
            return 1;
        }

        if (leftIndex > rightindex){
            return 1;
        }

        return -1;
    }
};
```